# Diff util not updating items in recycler

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, mutablelivedata, android-diffutils

I have problems updating data into recycler view. Im using adapter with diffutil

```
class DiffUtilCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<SectorItemDataUI>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: SectorItemDataUI, newItem: SectorItemDataUI): Boolean {
        return oldItem.sectorId == newItem.sectorId
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: SectorItemDataUI, newItem: SectorItemDataUI): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

}
```

In the viewModel i have the liveData

```
private val _sectorItem: MutableLiveData<MutableList<SectorItemDataUI>> =
        MutableLiveData()
val sectorItem: LiveData<MutableList<SectorItemDataUI>> get() = _sectorItem
```

I have this method to update the values (only temperature or humidity)

```
private fun updateMeasurementItem(measurement: List<NetworkMeasurement>) {
        val lastMeasurement = measurement.lastOrNull() ?: return

        _sectorItem.value = _sectorItem.value.also {
            it?.find { item -> item.temperatureSensorId == lastMeasurement.sensorId }?.temperature =
                lastMeasurement.value.toString()
            it?.find { item -> item.humiditySensorId == lastMeasurement.sensorId }?.humidity =
                lastMeasurement.value.toString()
        }
    }
```

And in the fragment i update the list into te recycler

```
viewModel.sectorItem.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
      homeSectorAdapter.submitList(it)
}
```

But for some reason, the data in the recycler is not updating. If i put Log before homeSectorAdapter.submitList(it), the data is correctly displayed in the logcat

if i create new instances of the data, the recycler updates correctly the data. But i know taht this isnt a good practice, so i dont want to make this.

```
private fun setupObservers() {
        viewModel.sectorItem.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { data ->
            val aux: MutableList<SectorItemDataUI> = mutableListOf()
            data.forEach {
                aux.add(
                    SectorItemDataUI(
                        it.sectorId,
                        it.sectorName,
                        it.temperature,
                        it.temperatureSensorId,
                        it.humidity,
                        it.humiditySensorId
                    )
                )
            }
            homeSectorAdapter.submitList(aux)
        }
    }
```

Comment: "if i create new instances of the data, the recycler updates correctly the data. But i know taht this isnt a good practice, so i dont want to make this." - no, that's exactly what you're supposed to be doing. Otherwise your `oldItem == newItem` is always going to be `true` since you haven't actually made a new item at all. What gave you the impression that you shouldn't be doing that?

Comment: Maybe I was wrong with that assumption. But I thought creating new instances all the time for every time I have to update data was a waste of memory.

Are there more elegant way to do the same?

Comment: Making new items is the only way to use DiffUtil. Don't worry about memory unless your list is many thousands of items long and fully loaded in memory at once. You also should not be using MutableList as your type in the LiveData. Use a read-only List to help prevent the possibility of you accidentally reusing a List instance, which would also break DiffUtil.

Comment: And last question. Suppose I have 5 elements in the recycler. Each element has 2 textviews. I need to update only one textview of one of this items. So... the item in the recycler is updating only this textview,only  the item with the new data is created but nothing happens with the other four, or the five elements are created again?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be good, maybe in the update method in your adapter.

Try with something like this :

```kotlin
fun updateList(
    newItems: List<SectorItemDataUI>,
    readOnly: Boolean = false,
) {
    val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(object : DiffUtil.Callback() {
        override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
            return this@HomeSectorAdapter.items.size
        }

        override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
            return newItems.size
        }

        override fun areItemsTheSame(
            oldItemPosition: Int,
            newItemPosition: Int,
        ): Boolean {
            return (this@HomeSectorAdapter.items[oldItemPosition]::class == newItems[newItemPosition]::class) && (this@HomeSectorAdapter.items[oldItemPosition].sectorId == newItems[newItemPosition].sectorId)
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(
            oldItemPosition: Int,
            newItemPosition: Int,
        ): Boolean {
            return this@HomeSectorAdapter.items[oldItemPosition]::class == newItems[newItemPosition]::class && this@HomeSectorAdapter.items[oldItemPosition] == newItems[newItemPosition]
        }
    })
    with(this@HomeSectorAdapter.items) {
        clear()
        addAll(newItems)
    }
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
}
```

The clear and addAll is used to update the model completely and the diffUtil is used to tell the adapter which items must be updated in the view (only content or ViewHolder completely).